# Best practive practice for accessing database on backend of asp dot net core application

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I am building a web app that consists of a frontend, a database and a backend. The front end can read data from the db and display it. The backend simply updates the database. I am using asp-dot-net core and 
I am not new to programming in general, but new to asp dot net core and it would be nice to have some advice on my design :)

In Startup.cs -> ConfigureServices() I use

```
services.AddDbContext<Database.FeedContext>(options => options.UseSqlite("DataSource=main.db"));
```

to init my database.
I know, that I can do something like this in a Controller-class (for example my frontend)

```cs
public class FrontendController : Controller
{
    private Database.FeedContext db;

    public FrontendController(Database.FeedContext db)
    {
        this.db = db;
        ...
    }
}
```

In this case the db will be provided by the framework via dependcy-injection.
BUT my backend is just a static class with various async functions. It seems wrong to do something like this:

```cs
public static class Backend
{
    private static Database.FeedContext db;

    static Backend()
    {
        db = new Database.FeedContext();
        ...
    }
}
```

Note: the backend does not have any state, except for the db-instance.

In the end my questions are:

1. Is it good practice to build the backend as a static class?
2. What is a good way to a database instance into the backend?
3. And can/should I use dependency injection for this?
4. Any other advice?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No: in this case the DbContext should not be shared among different requests.  Let the DI container manage service lifetime for you, since that is most typically the reason people gravitate towards static or singleton classes.
2. There are many "good" ways that all typically involve an ORM.  In general, you'd want to abstract database access behind a service that exposes simple types rather than database types.  This lets you change out the implementation later, perhaps delegating to a caching layer or a mock for testing your controllers.
3. Yes, and make sure you request *interfaces* in your controller constructor parameters, rather than concrete types.
4. The 'dotnet' command can generate project templates that provide a starting point for learning about data access; the current Microsoft-supplied ORM is Entity Framework.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db, for example.